# Using nginx-rtmp-module to save rtmp stream to mp4 instead of flv

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, mp4, rtmp, flv

I am trying to save an incoming rtmp stream on my server as an mp4 file. I am using the `nginx-rtmp` module and changing the container from `flv` to `mp4`  on the `exec_record_done` directive. This is done using ffmpeg as follows

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv output.mp4
```

I am sending h264 video streams and aac audio streams (*in an flv container*), so as to keep it compatible even with mp4

**I would like to know if it is possible to directly save the incoming stream as an mp4** and avoid the transcoding at the end of each session

> I am guessing this will help avoid the abrupt CPU spikes that I see when a recording is done

*`nginx.conf`*

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;
        allow publish all;
        allow play all;

        application live {
            live on;

            record all;
            record_suffix .flv;
            record_path /tmp/videos/;
            record_unique on;

            exec_record_done ffmpeg -y -i $path  /home/ubuntu/videos/$basename.mp4;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought this would be simple enough because the underlying streams remain the same. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: MP4 is not a live streaming format (it is progressively downloaded as a stored file). MP4 encoders need all the data available because an MP4's metadata lists all keyframes and the timings of each frame in video etc. Metadata in such a case cannot exist until all data is known (recording is finished). Possible **solution** If it's only video then maybe store the H264 (and mux after recording). If you have audio too then you'll need an a/v container. Maybe try outputting as **fragmented MP4** format if you don't like FLV containers.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your FFmpeg command is incorrect, try this:

```
exec_record_done ffmpeg -i $path -c copy /home/ubuntu/videos/$basename.mp4;
```

Remember to add the `-c copy` to tell FFmpeg convert FLV to MP4 without transcoding.

Another solution is copying the HLS files and covert HLS to MP4 by yourself.